# Running sbt in a Docker Container

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

I am trying to use Github actions for my scala project and created a Docker workflow for it. Basically, I am trying to install sbt into my container and run the project.

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM centos:centos8
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.13.1
ENV SBT_VERSION 1.5.2

RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y wget

# INSTALL JAVA
RUN yum install -y java-11-openjdk

# INSTALL SBT
RUN wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm
RUN yum install -y sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm

RUN wget -O /usr/local/bin/sbt-launch.jar http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/$SBT_VERSION/sbt-launch.jar

WORKDIR /root
EXPOSE 8080

RUN sbt compile
CMD sbt run
```

But when I push anything, I get the following error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c wget http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/rpm/sbt-${SBT_VERSION}.rpm' returned a non-zero code: 8
```

When I check the link manually (by setting the sbt version), I see indeed bintray responds with 403 forbidden error but status.bintray.com tells all systems are operational.

Am I doing something wrong or is something wrong with bintray?

Comment: Why not just using this: https://github.com/olafurpg/setup-scala?

Comment: `ENV NAME=value`

Comment: @ghik Adding this also didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forbidden doesnt mean non operational.
I think that url is incorrect as its not hosted on bintray rather jfrog, please see section on Centos which states

> ## remove old Bintray repo file

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html